# why Design view in android studio doesn't work

Tags: android-studio

I've been using the emulator but the design view would help me to drag and drop UI changes . But, it isn't running 
I've tried to load , refresh but still it isn't working 
What could be done ?

Comment: When selecting "Design View" you can also choose sdk and hardware type, try changing it. Mine does not render for some sdk that are not installed.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, from the menu, try **File->Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Answer (score 0):

Open build.gradle (module) change support libraries version to `28.0.0-alpha1` like below example

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use this step.

1- Go to your res folder and inside res folder.
    2-Go to values.
    3-Go to style.xml
    4-change  <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    to <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```